# Is a .properties-file suitable for storing hierarchical settings-objects?

Tags: java, properties-file

I have been tasked with an assignement at work, that needs persistance of client side settings. These settings are represented by a XML-file in the C# version of the framework I am implementing, and it represents objects with an hierarchical structure of up to six levels. Also, the number of objects in the different levels are sometimes arbitrary, like an ArrayList. Object serialization is unfortunately not an option, due to a requirement of being able to edit the file directly. It has been more than implied that I have to implement the persistance of these settings as a .properties-file, but I am having some concerns about if that is a good idea.

As far as I know, a .properties-file can only be used in the same way as a HashMap, with a key-value pairing of only Strings. The representation of complex objects seems only possible with long, complex key strings, representing the whole "path" of every single element, including it's individual index in possibly several lists.

```
filters.filter3.traces.rule4.add1.value="8"
```

I have not been able to find any decent ways to persist hierarchical objects in a .properties-file, but I have not been able to find any definite proof that it is not possible, either.

**So, is a .properties-file suitable for storing hierarchical settings-objects? Or should I implement my properties as an XML-file or JSON instead?**

Comment: Take a look at JSON. For example, [GSON](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) supports an easy serialization to JSON.

Comment: I am familiar with JSON, but can it be combined with a .properties-file? I have not been able to find an example of that.

Comment: Even if you use properties file, won't editing the file manually break the deserialization?

Comment: In my opinion they become extremely hard to read when there is a lot of hierarchical objects. Not to mention a really bad way of reading and writing.

Comment: @DmitryGinzburg: JSON isn't really intended to be human-writable; lack of comment syntax is one example.  YAML might be a better fit (I will assume that a decent Java YAML library exists ;)

Comment: Guys, thanks for all the comments, but none of you are actually answering the question. I am looking for proof in one way or another if .properties is suitable for hierarchical structures. I already have plenty of options I could use, I just need to convince my boss that .properties file format is not suitable in this case, or find a way to make it work WITH a .properties-file. Comprende?

Comment: @manouti, Yes it would break serialization, if the object were serialized. That is why serialization is not an option, as I at least tried to state in my original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would stick with an XML file. Nothing irritates users more than having different formats with different variants of an API framework.

You can use libraries such as Apache XMLBeans to simplify the process of reading and writing to XML files, using schema files to auto-generate appropriate Java classes.

Properties files can be used to store hierarchical data, but it's a real pain to edit that stuff by hand and it's easy to introduce errors. Some would argue that XML editing isn't a breeze either, but at least there exists editors that can make this easier when linked with an XSD.

Comment: This pretty much confirms what I already suspected. You don't happen to have any links to an article that confirms this? Or anyone else for that matter?

Comment: @KjetilNordin No, not really. I could Google for some, but I guess you've already done that. And why would an article be more definitive? Perhaps just let this question settle for a while and point out how many up-votes various answers received.

Comment: I've tried a lot at least. It couldn't really find anything either for or against, but no good examples. A lack of resources does not always mean that it is not possible though, So I really needed some help trying to find anything on the subject. I would love a written article source of some kind, but a set of second opinions is also very useful. Your answer is the best so far. I'll let it stay open for a little while longer. Stack Exchange does not really open up for opinion-based questions and answers, but unless one provides some kind of proof, I'll accept yours. ;)

Answer (score 2):

You have a perfect example in the form of `log4j`: here is property sample from [here](http://www.benmccann.com/blog/sample-log4j-properties-file/).

```
log4j.appender.R = org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.R.File = logs/bensApps.log
log4j.appender.R.Append = true
log4j.appender.R.DatePattern = '.'yyy-MM-dd
log4j.appender.R.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.R.layout.ConversionPattern = %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %c{1} [%p] %m%n
```

If you have a hierarchy in those keys, like:

```
Map<String,Object> root = new HashMap<>();
root.put("level1", "foobar");
root.put("level2", Collections.singletonMap("p", "foobar");
```

It is up to you to translate it into:

```
level1=foobar
level2.p=foobar
```

And when reading the file, to split `.` into submap:

```
Map<String, Object> root = new HashMap<>();
Properties propz = new Properties();
// load from your file
for (Map.Entry<String,Object> entry : propz.entrySet()) {
  String[] path = entry.getKey().split('\\.');
  Map<String,Object> parent = root;
  int n = path.length - 1;
  for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    String p = path[i];
    Object child = parent.get(p);
    if (null == child) {
      Map<String,Object> _p = new HashMap<>();
      parent.put(p, _p);
      parent = _p;      
    } else if (child instanceof Map) {
      parent = (Map<String,Objext>) child;
    } else {
      // it is up to you to do something when the path extends beyond a "final" key
    }
  }
  parent.put(path[n], entry.getValue());
}
```

However, this is a "reinvent the wheel" pattern, the other answers point you probably better solution than doing it by yourself. This example also show you one kind of problem:

```
p1=foobar
p1.p2=foobar
```

In the case of a machine generated properties, this won't happen, and an exception is perhaps the best answer. But in the case of human manipulated properties, this may have some meaning.

On a side note, since Java 7 come with JAXB, you can also do it in full XML, without requiring additional libraries. And using a hierarchy of some sort.

Comment: I think this is a great description of the complexity that might occur both in reading/writing of hierarchical properties, as well as possible errors, as objects could be set to both a simple String, and an object with several fields, or children objects. I am already using JAXB in my project, and the configurations already exist as an XML-file for the C# .net version of the framework. I fail to see the benefit of doing this in .properties, and I interpret your combined responses in the same way.

Comment: I think, in the case of log4j, it was before the XML configuration mode. And it depends on your need and the complexity of the things you need to configure. I would stick to properties for simple key=value.

Answer (score 1):

I have always found this way of storing hierarchical configuration data quite cumbersome, but it is very well possible. For example, it is (used to be?) the most common way of configuring Log4j, but from my experience, more and more developers are switching to XML here as well.

I really fail to see the point of using properties files for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

I think you've already got the gist of it - Java properties files can express hierarchies, but awkwardly.

Take a look at the [Typesafe Config library](https://github.com/typesafehub/config), which is what [Play Framework](https://www.playframework.com/) uses. Its primary language is HOCON (human-optimized config notation) which is great for expressing hierarchical properties. The library also plays well with both properties files and JSON, so you can easily support any and all of these languages simultaneously.

In a Java properties file, as you've said, you're restricted to only using dotted keys

```
a.b.c = 42
```

In HOCON, you can choose to either do that or to nest sections with curly braces. So that example could be expressed in any of the following ways:

```
a.b.c : 42

a {
    b.c : 42
}

a.b {
    c : 42
}

a {
    b {
        c : 42
    }
}
```