# What technology to manage evolutive configurations on 1-tier software

Tags: java, xml, configuration

I have a Java application software that evolves. It uses a configuration file at launch to load configuration values. As the software evolves, the configuration evolves too. Some keys are no longer used, new keys are added, eventually some keys are renamed, some values have different type.

The question is, what it the best technology to use for configuration management in my case?

The requirements are:

- store and load configuration information to and from one file,
- manage complex values (such as maps),
- manage missing values,
- manage evolution in value types,
- manage key renaming,
- manage no longer used key/value pairs.

So far, YAML did not meet all listed requirements.

Could XML with JAXB marshaling and unmarshaling meet the requirements or will I encounter problems there too?

Comment: Versionize and have your code support all versions.

Comment: I think what you mean by "evolving software" is just regular software with continuing development. How do you expect software to work normally when the configuration is potentially broken?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen I had not thought about that solution. Would you, by any chance, know where could I find more information about that?

Comment: @Kayaman Yes, it is indeed just a regular software with continuing development. My question is precisely how to keep it working no matter what configuration is used.

Comment: A simple property file can be used for this end. It's more about how you intend to make your program work so that any new parameter isn't considered mandatory, which an old configuration wouldn't have.

Comment: @Kayaman On one hand, the `Properties.getProperty(String key, String defaultValue)` enables to manage new keys and missing keys. But one the other hand, a simple property file doesn't play well with complex values, as discussed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1380156/java-properties-properties-files-vs-xml) and [there](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25970045/is-a-properties-file-suitable-for-storing-hierarchical-settings-objects).

Comment: Well your question is quite vague, so what do you really expect? Edit your question to include actual examples of your configurations and functionality of your software.